# addJavascriptInterface : object method not found

Tags: android

I wrote new example similar to WebView Demo and registered my Java object with addJavascriptInterface() to webview. and in Java script I am able to call java methods.

Later, I modified android browser code and tried to add Object to javascript,in a same way. but object members are not accessible in javascript and I get runtime error like

"Uncaught TypeError: Object com.android.browser.BrowserActivity$MyJavaScriptInterface@43bf7eb8 has no method 'launchPlayer' "

Where as launchPlayer method is available in MyJavaScriptInterface class.

Can anybody tell me what is the difference in Browser app, which stops exporting methods to Javascript.

Comment: Make sure your inner class and the method are both `public`.

Comment: Make sure you set your android target SDK version to maximum 15 (or lower).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031635/android-4-2-1-webview-and-javascript-interface-breaks ,  for >= 4.2.1 add @JavascriptInterface to method

Comment: Are you sure parameters are same?